# How to find statistical significance on SPSS?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss

i have 3 separate variables - Depression, Anxiety and Stress - each of them have been answered as Yes or No. These were answered by Case group and the Control group. Now I need to find if each of these variables are statistically  significant in either case group or the control group. How can this be done on SPSS?

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is associations between dichotomous variables: is Depression associated with Group (control versus case)?

This is usually done with a [chi-square independence test](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-chi-square-independence-test/). Note that this requires some statistical assumptions.

Before doing so, I recommend inspecting some [descriptives](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/association-between-categorical-or-dichotomous-variables/) for the pairs of variables.

Comment: Hey! Yes, I need to find out if depression is statistically significant in controls or in cases or in both. So is Chi-square the choice of analysis for this?